# Missing Monero in My Monero-GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My iPhone crashed, I changed to an Android phone and I could not access my Cake Wallet, but managed to recover to Monero-GUI wallet. The amount shown in this wallet was correct.

I then transferred all my XMR from Monero-GUI to my Binance account on May 1 2019.  My Monero-GUI wallet immediately shows a Zero balance (but strangely also show zero history); it has been over a month but still
my Binance account has not received the XMR coins. My Monero-GUI screen shows that my "Wallet is synchronised" and "Daemon is synchronised (1860054)".

How do I recover the XMR coins that seem to be stuck somewhere in the blockchain?

Appreciate your help.
Thanks....teocl

Comment: Can you post the transaction hash / ID?

Comment: Going to mark this as duplicate. I *think* you simply forgot to add the payment ID to the transaction. As such, you will have to contact Binance's support to resolve the issue. If that is not the issue, please let me know in the comments.